# Generating line on canvas doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a simple script which will generate a line on canvas. What I wanted to achive is to have it start from the middle of the canvas and end in a random point of the canvas.

Here is a demo:

```js
const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var _x = window.getComputedStyle(c).width;
var _y = window.getComputedStyle(c).height;

//Get canvas size
var x = (c.width = Number(_x.substring(0, _x.length - 2)));
var y = (c.height = Number(_y.substring(0, _y.length - 2)));

//Turn variables from string to int

function getRandomPoint(x, y) {
  //Generate random point within the canvas
  var px = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
  var py = Math.floor(Math.random() * y);
  var cord = [px, py];
  return cord;
}

var cord = getRandomPoint(x, y);
createLine(x, y, cord[0], cord[1]);

function createLine(x, y, xk, yk) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x / 2, y / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(xk, yk);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body{
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}



/* CANVAS */

canvas{
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color:white;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

If you open the demo and see empty canvas try refreshing it few times. Sometimes the line will appear and most times it won't. Also it usually doesn't start in the middle of the canvas.

I have no idea why does that happen, it's my first time experimenting with canvas so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put width and height of your canvas in html attributes:

```js
const c = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = c.getContext('2d');

//Get canvas size
var x = window.getComputedStyle(c).width;
var y = window.getComputedStyle(c).height;
//Turn variables from string to int
x = Number(x.substring(0,x.length-2));
y = Number(y.substring(0,y.length-2));

function getRandomPoint(x,y){
    //Generate random point within the canvas
    px = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
    py = Math.floor(Math.random()*y);
    cord = [px, py];
    return cord;
}

var cord = getRandomPoint(x,y);
createLine(x,y,cord[0],cord[1]);

function createLine(x,y,xk,yk){
    ctx.moveTo(x/2,y/2);
    ctx.lineTo(xk,yk);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body{
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}



/* CANVAS */

canvas{
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color:white;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I see thanks, I thought setting it up in css would be enough

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the canvas width & height in javascript.

```js
const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var _x = window.getComputedStyle(c).width;
var _y = window.getComputedStyle(c).height;

//Get canvas size
//Turn variables from string to int
var x = (c.width = Number(_x.substring(0, _x.length - 2)));
var y = (c.height = Number(_y.substring(0, _y.length - 2)));



function getRandomPoint(x, y) {
  //Generate random point within the canvas
  var px = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
  var py = Math.floor(Math.random() * y);
  var cord = [px, py];
  return cord;
}

var cord = getRandomPoint(x, y);
createLine(x, y, cord[0], cord[1]);

function createLine(x, y, xk, yk) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x / 2, y / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(xk, yk);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body{
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}



/* CANVAS */

canvas{
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color:white;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you simply forgot to add the width and height to your canvas HTML node

```
<canvas id="canvas" height=400 width=600></canvas>
```

Comment: @Jan The CSS defines the box the canvas element exists in. The HTML attributes determines the width and height of the canvas context.